# restangular multiple api sources

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I can set one api provider per angularjs app for restangular like this

```
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/api');
```

but how do i setup multiple base url's and use them selectively.
I want to configure and use both of below end points

```
      RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/api');

      RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8090/apiws');
```

how do I do it with Restangular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's found in the [docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

```
factory("service1", ["Restangular", function(restangular) {
  return restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {

    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8090/apiws");

  });

}]);


factory("service2", ["Restangular", function(restangular) {
  return restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {

    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:8080/api");
    RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({
      "Authorization": "Basic 123345667",
    });

  });

}]);
```

Comment: how to declare those URL's in route.js